# Large TTL for expiring records in Scylla/Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, scylla

I have an use-case where I need to delete the records from Scylla table after 18 months. Is it advisable to put a large `default_time_to_live` in Cassandra/Scylla tables?  The table grows at ~2M records/day.

Sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE heartrate_ttl (
    pet_chip_id  uuid,
    name text,
    heart_rate int,
    PRIMARY KEY (pet_chip_id))
WITH default_time_to_live = 47304000;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR;**

An 18 month TTL should work just fine for the next 12.5 years.

**Long version**

The current `MAX_TTL` is defined in the source as `20 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60`; 20 years. However, at the time of this writing Cassandra TTLs are still subject to [The Year 2038 Problem](https://theyear2038problem.com/). For a TTL of 18 months, this means that write operations will begin failing on 2036-07-01 at 03:14:07

For those considering extremely large TTLs, I highly recommend reading through [CASSANDRA-14092](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14092?attachmentOrder=desc) and [CASSANDRA-14227](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14227?attachmentOrder=desc).

Comment: Note that https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14227 was already fixed in Cassandra 5.0, which isn't yet available - but should be soonish. ScyllaDB hasn't yet fixed this issue (see https://github.com/scylladb/scylladb/issues/15116) but presumably it will be fixed during the next 12.5 years, so you should be completely safe with your 18-month TTL on ScyllaDB too.